# How should fixed flex sizes for Angular Material be defined?

Tags: angularjs, flexbox, angular-material

I got following markup

```
<div layout="column" layout-align="space-around center" ng-cloak>
  <div flex="85">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="space-around center">
      <div flex>
        <md-button class="md-fab md-warn" ui-sref="settings">
          <ng-md-icon icon="settings" style="fill:white"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
        <span class="md-subhead">Configuraciones</span>
      </div>
      <div flex>
        <md-button class="md-fab md-primary" aria-label="Eat cake" ng-click="watch()">
          <ng-md-icon icon="play_arrow" style="fill:white"></ng-md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div flex="15">
    <div layout="row" layout-align="space-around center">
      <div flex>
        <img src="public/img/buap-logo.png" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block finalcut-img-small" style=""/>
      </div>
      <div flex>
        <img src="public/img/lke-logo.jpg" class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block finalcut-img-small" style=""/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Producing following:

[image]

However I need the buttons div to take 85% of its parent container height, that's why I've added `flex="85"` attribute, while the div with images should be 15% of the height.

I'm not sure how I should set their properties to get it like that. According to docs that should make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex only works with width. There's no way to use flex to tell the height of a div.
The property layout="column" only means the divs are showing from top to bottom, and row from left to right.

From material.angular.org

> column:   Items arranged vertically. max-width = 100% and max-height is the height of the items in the container.

You can use in the img tag a css style like 'height:15vh' and give it a try

Comment: view height, is a css property tell the element adjust to use a X% of the viewport, not just the parent. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp